# How to calculate this sum using orthonormal closed system?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

Let $\left\{\phi_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a closed orthonormal system of real valued
functions in the inner product space V of continuous piecewise continuously
differentiable functions on [0, 1] with the inner product $$
\langle f, g\rangle=f(0) \overline{g(0)}+\int_{0}^{1} f^{\prime}(t) \overline{g^{\prime}(t)} d t
$$
Calculate : $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\alpha \phi_{n}(0)+\int_{0}^{a} \phi_{n}^{\prime}(t) d t\right)\left(\beta \phi_{n}(0)+\int_{0}^{b} \phi_{n}^{\prime}(t) d t\right)
$$
while $\alpha , \beta$ are complex numbers and $0\leq a,b \leq1$

My idea was to open the integrals values in the sum and get $$\int_{0}^{a} \phi_{n}^{\prime}(t) d t = \phi_{n}(a) - \phi_{n}(0)$$
$$\int_{0}^{b} \phi_{n}^{\prime}(t) d t = \phi_{n}(b) - \phi_{n}(0)$$
But it doesn't go well and I am losing the similarity for the inner product.
I thought on another idea define a piece wise smooth function which get the value 1 in some interval and $0$ otherwise but I am not sure how to perform this idea (if it is true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the coordinates of the following functions:
$$f(x)=\left\{\matrix{ \alpha+x& \text{if }x<a\\
\alpha+a& \text{if }x\ge a}\right.\\
g(x)=\left\{\matrix{ \beta+x& \text{if }x<b\\
\beta+b& \text{if }x\ge b}\right.
$$

Comment: Yes I thought on that idea and than stopped since the issue of the complex numbers. do you think this can be acceptable solution?

Comment: Actually, already the definition of the inner product contains complex conjugation, so I guess it's already for *complex valued* functions. But even if not, we can extend it for them.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For functions $f,g \in V$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \langle \phi_n,g\rangle = \langle f,g\rangle.$$

Comment: Very nice, our two hints give a full solution :)